# How to wait in a request and response in another request with koa

Tags: node.js, koa

I wanna await the reponse in a request until I set value in another request. How to code this in koa?

> request 1:  /always-get?key=abc
>   request 2: /set?key=abc&val=1234

```
var querystring = require("querystring");

module.exports = resTest = {
    awaitRes: function *(next) {
        var qs = querystring.parse(this.request.querystring);
        var key = qs.key;
        resTest.qrResponses[key] = this.response;
        // I wanna wait here, response in the next method
    },

    setRes: function *(next) {
        var qs = querystring.parse(this.request.querystring);
        var key = qs.key;
        var val = qs.val;
        //reponse here....
        resTest.qrResponses[key].body = val;  
        this.body = "OK";
    },
    qrResponses: {}

};


router.get("/always-get", resTest.awaitRes);

router.get("/set", resTest.setRes);
```

This is easy in callback hell framework...

Answer (score 1):

You can create an event bus to share events between them. Also, `co` will yield to a thunk and provide a callback. So you can `yield` a thunk and call the callback when you've "heard" the event with the same name emitted. Once that callback is called, the middleware chain will continue.

```
var Emitter = require('events');
var bus = new Emitter();

router.get('/info/:key', function* (next) {
  var ctx = this;
  // yield a thunk
  yield function(cb) {
    // this has the potential to leak event listeners!
    bus.once(ctx.params.key, function(value) {
      ctx.body = value;
      cb();
    });
  };
});

router.get('/set/:key/:value', function* (next) {
  bus.emit(this.params.key, this.params.value);
  this.body = 'OK';
});
```

Comment: potentially you'd want to re-assign `bus` to a `new Emitter` on each request?